# node.js - issue with faye-websocket-node as client and sockjs-node as server

Tags: node.js, sockjs

I'm trying to use `faye-websocket-node ^0.11.0` as client, `sockjs-node 0.3.18` as server, please refer to below client/server code

**Issue:**

- if client and server `prefix` matchs, like below code `prefix = /hello`, client will throw `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`
- I tried using `prefix = /` on the server, this time there won't be any error message, but there's no connection open, no message printed from either client or server `on open` or `on connection` code

**Question:**

How to use `faye-websocket-node` as client, `sockjs-node` as server, and have them communicate via websock using node.js?

Thanks!

*client code*:

```
var WebSocket = require('faye-websocket'),
    ws        = new WebSocket.Client('ws://127.0.0.1:8888/hello');

ws.on('open', function(event) {
  console.log('open');
  ws.send('Hello, world!');
});

ws.on('message', function(event) {
  console.log('message', event.data);
});

ws.on('close', function(event) {
  console.log('close', event.code, event.reason);
  ws = null;
});

ws.on('error', function(event){
  console.log('error', event.message);
});
```

*server code*:

```
var sockjs = require('sockjs');
var http = require('http');

var sockjsServer = sockjs.createServer({
  sockjs_url: '//d1fxtkz8shb9d2.cloudfront.net/sockjs-0.3.min.js'
});

sockjsServer.on('connection', function(conn) {
  console.log('on connection');
  conn.on('data', function(msg) {
    console.log('\nRECV:'+msg);
  });
});

var server = http.createServer();
sockjsServer.installHandlers(server, {prefix:'/hello'});
server.listen(8888, '0.0.0.0');
```

Answer (score 0):

I raised ticket[#229](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/issues/229), answer from [`sockjs-node`](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node):

```
You cannot use faye-websocket directly as SockJS utilizes additional framing. You can do one of two things:

1. Use the "raw" endpoint as documented in the README: https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node#connecting-to-sockjs-node-without-the-client
2. Use sockjs-client from Node.js! Client versions >= 1.0 support usage directly from Node.
```